# Why $\mathrm{arccot}(-2) = \pi-\mathrm{arccot}(2) \lor 2\pi+\mathrm{arccot}(2)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving a basic trigonometric equation involving cot and my solution is $\mathrm{arccot}(-2)+k\pi$ but according to the book the solutions are $\pi-\mathrm{arccot}(2)+k\pi \lor 2\pi+\mathrm{arccot}(2)+k\pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The equation is the following: $\cot(x)=-2$.

Comment: *You* are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct. You are right to say that

$$\cot(x)=-2 \iff x=\mathrm{arccot}(-2) + k\pi\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb Z$$

On the other hand, $2\pi+\mathrm{arccot}(2)+k\pi$ is not a solution, since $\cot$ is $\pi$-periodic, so we have

$$\cot(2\pi+\mathrm{arccot}(2)+k\pi)=\cot(\mathrm{arccot(2)})=2$$

Finally, we indeed have $\mathrm{arccot}(-2)=\pi-\mathrm{arccot}(2)$. For, let $\alpha=\pi-\mathrm{arccot}(2)$. Then

$$\cot(\alpha)=\cot(-\mathrm{arccot}(2))=-\cot(\mathrm{arccot}(2))=-2$$

This implies that $\alpha=\mathrm{arccot}(-2)+q\pi$ for some $q$ in $\mathbb Z$. But the range of $\mathrm{arccot}$ is $(0,\pi)$, so $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$, therefore $q=0$.

Comment: Since $\alpha=\pi-arccot(2)$ why $cot(\alpha)$ = $cot(-arccot(2))$ ? Furthermore, is there a particular reason to express the solution that way instead of just $arccot(-2)+k\pi?$

Comment: 1. Because $\cot$ is $\pi$-periodic. 2. In general, no particular reason. Maybe it could be useful in some specific situations